# runtest tesng.xml does not run any test

Tags: maven, selenium, automation, testng

When I try to execute my automated tests with:

> runtest.bat testng.xml

and I get this:

```
===============================================
Selenium Tests
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

The solutions I found are:

- clean the project -> did not work
- check the @Test annotations before every automated test-> yes. I have them
- check the import: import org.testng.annotations.Test; -> yes I have it

I ran out of ideas, could anyone help me? Thanks

The complete pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.ohim.copla</groupId>
    <artifactId>copla-selenium</artifactId>
    <name>copla-selenium</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>eu.ohim</groupId>
        <artifactId>esearch-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0-RC1.2</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jboss.version>7.1.1.Final</jboss.version>
  </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>zip</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>mp3</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/shade.xml</descriptor>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/delivery-test.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>               
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-clean</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>target</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>failsafe-reports/**/*.*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>           

        </plugins>
    </build>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-integration</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope> 
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>   
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.nitorcreations</groupId>
      <artifactId>matchers</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-jxpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-jxpath</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
        <artifactId>ifxjdbc_10</artifactId>
        <version>10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>        
         <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>         
         <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>         
         <version>1.1.2</version>         
         <scope>test</scope>         
    </dependency>

    <dependency>     
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>     
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>     
        <version>3.0</version>     
        <scope>test</scope> 
    </dependency> 

  </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- needed for Bamboo -->
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefirePluginVersion}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/bin/testng-qc-sanity-regression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>  
                    </plugin> 

                    <plugin>             
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>             
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>             
                        <version>2.5</version>             
                        <configuration>                 
                        <properties>                     
                            <property>                         
                                <name>listener</name>                         
                                <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>                     
                            </property>                 
                        </properties>                 
                        </configuration>         
                    </plugin>                   
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <!-- needed for Bamboo -->      
            <id>deploy-tomcat</id>
        </profile>  

    </profiles>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this similar issue, i think u have imported external libraries also, please remove all your libraries from build path as dependencies are already added in POM.xml, now refresh your project and now run the maven test, it should work, please keep me posted I can guide you through this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I tried but I'm still getting the same, any other ideas?

Comment: then i think there is a problem the way you have setup your POM.xml, I also see that you have individually pasted selenium jar dependencies, its always to add dependencies from the dependency tab of POM.xml rather than pasting in POM tab.

Comment: please go through this link for better setup:

http://www.toolsqa.com/java/maven/configure-selenium-continuous-integration-maven/

Comment: Thanks I already did it but from cmd with the command 'mvn clean package', I got the BUILD SUCCESS message. But when I try to run I get this: Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your testng xml file in POM.xml file.
The annotation @Test you are using is for testng tests. So Maven doesn't get the tests to be executed.
You need to add testng.xml file in your POM.xml file for any plugin such as maven-surefire-plugin like :

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
                   <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
 </suiteXmlFiles>
```